# php imagecopyresampled poor quality

Tags: php, image

I have a php script which saves the original image, then resizes it - one thumbnail and one larger image for web viewing. This works well except with some images the quality is terrible. It seems to be saved with a very low colour pallet. You can see the result at http://kalpaitch.com/index.php?filter=white - click on the first thumbnail with the title 'white white white'

Below is the code used for the image resampling:

```
function resizeImg($name, $extension, $size1, $size2) {
if (preg_match('/jpg|jpeg|JPG|JPEG/',$extension)){
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($name);
}
if (preg_match('/gif|GIF/',$extension)){
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($name);
}

$old_width = imageSX($image);
$old_height = imageSY($image);
$old_aspect_ratio = $old_width/$old_height; 

if($size2 == 0){
    $new_aspect_ratio = $old_aspect_ratio;
    if($old_width > $old_height){
        $new_width = $size1;
        $new_height = $new_width / $old_aspect_ratio;
    } else {
        $new_height = $size1;
        $new_width = $new_height * $old_aspect_ratio;
    }
} elseif($size2 > 0){
    $new_aspect_ratio = $size1/$size2;
    //for landscape potographs
    if($old_aspect_ratio >= $new_aspect_ratio) {
        $x1 = round(($old_width - ($old_width * ($new_aspect_ratio/$old_aspect_ratio)))/2);
        $old_width = round($old_width * ($new_aspect_ratio/$old_aspect_ratio));
        $y1 = 0;
        $new_width = $size1;
        $new_height = $size2;
        //for portrait photographs
    } else{
        $x1 = 0;
        $y1 = 0;
        $old_height = round($old_width/$new_aspect_ratio);
        $new_width = $size1;
        $new_height = $size2;
    }
}

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);

return $new_image;
```

Many Thanks

P.S.
[photos removed from server]

And here is the rest of the upload code:

```
// Move the original to the right place
        $result = @move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $origlocation);

        // Resize the image and save the thumbnail
        $new_image = resizeImg($origlocation, $extension, 500, 0);

        if (preg_match("/gif/",$extension)){
            imagegif($new_image, $normallocation); 
        } else {
            imagejpeg($new_image, $normallocation); 
        }

        // Resize the image and save the thumbnail
        $new_image = resizeImg($origlocation, $extension, 190, 120);

        if (preg_match("/gif/",$extension)){
            imagegif($new_image, $thumblocation); 
        } else { 
            imagejpeg($new_image, $thumblocation);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show a before-after example?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear, but it sounds like some of the images you're getting are a certain size and your script actually resizes it LARGER than it came originally? The quality will be terrible if you do that.

Comment: No the script will resize the image proportionally if only one size is given. If two sizes are given it will resize and the crop the rest without changing the aspect ratio.

The resampled images are always much much lower resolution than the original image. The before photo above is not the original, they are both the same resolution but the before is saved with photoshop and the after one is saved with my script.

Comment: Where is the rest of the script? It could be the image output function you're using. Try using imagepng() to output the image and set the compression quality to '0' for testing.

http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

Comment: I did a quick test and imagepng() didn't seem to make an awful lot of difference. Well none really. But I'm posting the other relevant half of the script FYI.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The loss in quality is down not to `imagecopyresampled()`, but to the JPEG compression. Unfortunately, GD's compression algorithms are no match to Photoshop's - in fact, very few are. But you can improve the result: GD's default JPG compression level is 75 of 100.

You can raise the quality using the third parameter to [**imagejpeg()**](http://www.php.net/imagejpeg) (which I assume you are using for the final output):

```
imagejpeg  ( $new_image, null, 99);
```

Play around in the 90-100 range. The image will become larger in file size than the original - that is going to be the price you pay. But it should be possible to achieve comparable quality.

Alternatively, as John Himmelman already says in the comments, try using `imagepng()` for better quality - also at the price of a notably larger file size, of course.

Comment: As a last little point for anyone who is curious. I have changed the imagejpeg() quality to 99 and I come away with a much much better image. Although - the difference between that and the default is a 1000% increase in filesize (default comes in at 12kb, high quality compression at 110kb)

Comment: Just a suggestion I came up with after reading this.  With my thumbnailing system, there's no requirement that the thumbnail image is the same format as the original full size image, my utility function is asked "what is the thumbnail file for this image, and does it already exist?" so if asked about file.jpg it would come back with thumbnail_cache/file.jpg.  I have altered this approach to always reply with .png format thumbnails, so if asked about file.jpg it comes back with thumbnail_cache/file.png and generates a png thumbnail.  This avoids any worries about GD jpg compression.

Comment: Result of resample is blurry, and it's a GD-problem, not supporting lanczos. A hack is to resize to 200% and then to 100% (50%) using imagescale. It's not lanczos, but sharper. ImageMagick is always better.

Answer (score 3):

well, php.net documentation says you should have a imagecreatetruecolor() image for your dest_image if you want to avoid using only a 255 color palette but you already do that.

I guess an alternative would be to use an external tools such as [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) with a system() call.

Comment: yea not sure php is being very helpful. As you can see I have done a third test image using imagecopyresized, which fares a little better but not enough.

Comment: Thank you, using imagecreatetruecolor solved the issue I was experiencing with my custom images having low color count!

Answer (score 2):

The quick an dirty trick is to **make the thumbnails 1000 x 1000 pixels** (or more) on `imagecopyresized()` then set the **JPEG quality to 20** or less on `imagejpeg($img, $savePath, 20);`. The output will usually be smaller than **100 kb**.

Let the client CSS do the resizing and the pictures will be fast to load and look flawless in modern browsers when scaled to thumbnail size.

Answer (score -1):

```
function img_resize( $tmpname, $size, $save_dir, $save_name, $maxisheight = 0 )
{
    $save_dir .= ( substr($save_dir,-1) != "/") ? "/" : "";
    $gis = getimagesize($tmpname);
    $type = $gis[2];

    switch($type)
    {
        case "1": $imorig = imagecreatefromgif($tmpname); break;
        case "2": $imorig = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);break;
        case "3": $imorig = imagecreatefrompng($tmpname); break;
        default:  $imorig = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);
    }

    $x = imagesx($imorig);
    $y = imagesy($imorig);

    $woh = (!$maxisheight)? $gis[0] : $gis[1] ;
    if($woh <= $size)
    {
        $aw = $x;
        $ah = $y;
    }
    else
    {
        if(!$maxisheight)
        {
            $aw = $size;
            $ah = $size * $y / $x;
        }
        else
        {
            $aw = $size * $x / $y;
            $ah = $size;
        }
    }
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($aw,$ah);

    if (imagecopyresampled($im,$imorig , 0,0,0,0,$aw,$ah,$x,$y))

    if (imagejpeg($im, $save_dir.$save_name))

        return true;

    else

        return false;

}
```

Comment: very little information of what is actually going on in this function. What should size be? an array? a string? percentage?