# Blurry downsizing a 400x400 to 300x300

Tags: php, image-resizing, image-compression

Ok, here is the issue, the 400x400 jpeg looks fine the quality is great. However when resized to 300x300 it looks like it has been pulled apart and put back together by a 2 year old.

here is the script

```
$image->resize(300,300);
```

which calls the following script

```
 function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }
```

[image: picture uploaded for resizing.]

[image]

Here is the image class

```
class SimpleImage {

   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {

      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }

   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=99, $permissions=null) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }


      if( $permissions != null) {

        chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }

    function getWidth() {

      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {

      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {

      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

  function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }   

}
```

Comment: Good question, but I feel the title can be made more specific.

Comment: @Jon how would title it

Comment: possible duplicate of [php imagecopyresampled poor quality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345605/php-imagecopyresampled-poor-quality)

Comment: missing the output step - is it imagejpeg?  And is the issue as @Theolodis suggests?

Comment: @AlisterBulman an issue with a jpeg being shrinked is mostly about jpeg (the algorithm) and the jpeg quality.

Comment: Just tried your code but used the GD routines directly. The quality is fine. although GD is not as powerful as 'ImageMagik' it is perfectly good at what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test your function I had to implement the rest of the class.  This works for me on PHP 5.5.14.  Your code is included here unaltered:

```
class image
{
    public $image = null;

    public function __construct($img)
    {
        $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
    }

    public function resize($width,$height) {
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }

    public function getWidth()
    {
        return imagesx($this->image);
    }

    public function getHeight()
    {
        return imagesy($this->image);
    }
}

$image = new image('img.jpg');

$image->resize(300,300);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image->image);
exit;
```

This gives me the following output, which is a little blurry, but much better than your example.

[image]

Comment: I found my issue - it was the fact I was sizing the image 80x80 and then upsizing it again to 300x300 my fault

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but just helping out and I can't put pictures in comments...

In case you are wondering whether it is going to be worth installing and using ImageMagick, I have done it for you below:

```
convert in.jpg -resize 300x300 out.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: How would I use this in PHP and is ImageMagick a Yum install - as it looks like you have given me a terminal command