# PHP upload resulting in blurry image

Tags: php, image

I'm using the a crop tool that can be found here: https://github.com/sconsult/croppic

I've modified it to suit my needs - apologies for the quantity of code, but I don't know which part of it *might* be causing an issue.

I first implemented this code around 5 - 6 months ago and it worked flawlessly. 85% quality was just right for every image tested. **The code has not changed since it's original implementation**, but the images are coming out very obviously blurry - they just don't look nice any more. I've tested with the same images previously uploaded to compare, and they don't look the same as the originally uploaded and cropped images.

The only major event that I know of that might affect this is upgrading our version of `PHP`. I believe it used to be `5.3xx` or similar at the time of implementation, and now we're running `5.6.18`. What might be causing blurryness? Are there any notable changes in `5.6.18` from `5.3` that could attribute to this?

**Please note I have tried changing the** `$jpeg_quality = 85;` **to 100**. Unfortunately all this does it increase the file size. The same blurryness occurs.

```
<?php
$image = $_POST['imgUrl'];
// original sizes
$img_init_w = $_POST['imgInitW'];
$img_init_h = $_POST['imgInitH'];
// resized sizes
$img_w = $_POST['imgW'];
$img_h = $_POST['imgH'];
// offsets
$imgY1 = $_POST['imgY1'];
$imgX1 = $_POST['imgX1'];
// crop box
$cropW = $_POST['cropW'];
$cropH = $_POST['cropH'];
// rotation angle
$angle = $_POST['rotation'];

$id = $_POST['id'];
$dtormob = $_POST['dtormob'];

$jpeg_quality = 85;



$original_filename = "../../..".WEB_ROOT."lib/img/$id-original";


// different filenames depending on whether this is for mobile or desktop
switch ($dtormob)
{
    case 'dt':
        $cropped_lrg_filename  = "../../..".WEB_ROOT."lib/img/$id-lrg-w"; // 1440 x 568
        $cropped_sml_filename  = "../../..".WEB_ROOT."lib/img/$id-med-w"; // 767 x 302

        $lrg_resized_w = 1440;
        $lrg_resized_h = 568;

        $sml_resized_w = 767;
        $sml_resized_h = 302;
        break;

    case 'mob':
        $cropped_lrg_filename  = "../../..".WEB_ROOT."lib/img/$id-med-s"; // 767 x 607
        $cropped_sml_filename  = "../../..".WEB_ROOT."lib/img/$id-sml-s"; // 480 x 380

        $lrg_resized_w = 767;
        $lrg_resized_h = 607;

        $sml_resized_w = 480;
        $sml_resized_h = 380;
        break;
}



$what = getimagesize($image);

switch(strtolower($what['mime']))
{
    case 'image/png':
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($image);
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($image);
        $type = '.png';
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        error_log('jpg');
        $type = '.jpeg';
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($image);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($image);
        $type = '.gif';
        break;
    default: die('image type not supported');
}


// Error checking
if (!is_writable(dirname($cropped_lrg_filename))) {
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => "Can't write cropped File, directory inaccesible"
    );
}
else if ($what[0] > 2000 || $what[1] > 2000) {
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => '<strong>Image too large</strong>, please upload an image <strong>2000 x 2000px</strong> or less.<br /><em>(No smaller than '.$lrg_resized_w.' x '.$lrg_resized_h.'px)</em>'
    );
}
else if ($what[0] < $lrg_resized_w || $what[1] < $lrg_resized_h) {
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => '<strong>Image too small</strong>, please upload an image <strong>'.$lrg_resized_w.' x '.$lrg_resized_h.'px</strong> or more.<br /><em>(No bigger than 2000 x 2000px)</em>'
    );
}
else if ($what['channels'] > 3) {
    $response = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => '<strong>Image format error</strong>, this image is in CMYK format, please convert it to <strong>RGB</strong> first.'
    );
}
else
{
    $original_filename_absolute = PROTOCOL.SUB_DOMAIN.DOMAIN.str_replace('../../..', '', $original_filename).$type;
    $cropped_lrg_filename_absolute = PROTOCOL.SUB_DOMAIN.DOMAIN.str_replace('../../..', '', $cropped_lrg_filename).$type;
    $cropped_sml_filename_absolute = PROTOCOL.SUB_DOMAIN.DOMAIN.str_replace('../../..', '', $cropped_sml_filename).$type;

    // remove any images that already exist
    if (file_exists($original_filename.$type)) {
        unlink($original_filename.$type);
    }
    if (file_exists($cropped_lrg_filename.$type)) {
        unlink($cropped_lrg_filename.$type);
    }
    if (file_exists($cropped_sml_filename.$type)) {
        unlink($cropped_sml_filename.$type);
    }


    // lets make a copy of the original
    // ====================================================================================
    $original_img = imagecreatetruecolor($img_init_w, $img_init_h);
    imagecopyresampled($original_img, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $img_init_w, $img_init_h, $img_init_w, $img_init_h);
    imagejpeg($original_img, $original_filename.$type, 100);




    // create large crop first - then resize after as it should be the same aspect ratio
    // ====================================================================================
    // resize the original image to size of editor
    $lrg_resized_image = imagecreatetruecolor($img_w, $img_h);
    imagecopyresampled($lrg_resized_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $img_w, $img_h, $img_init_w, $img_init_h);

    // rotate the rezized image
    $rotated_image = imagerotate($lrg_resized_image, -$angle, 0);

    // find new width & height of rotated image
    $rotated_width = imagesx($rotated_image);
    $rotated_height = imagesy($rotated_image);

    // diff between rotated & original sizes
    $dx = $rotated_width - $img_w;
    $dy = $rotated_height - $img_h;

    // crop rotated image to fit into original rezized rectangle
    $cropped_rotated_image = imagecreatetruecolor($img_w, $img_h);
    imagecolortransparent($cropped_rotated_image, imagecolorallocate($cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagecopyresampled($cropped_rotated_image, $rotated_image, 0, 0, $dx / 2, $dy / 2, $img_w, $img_h, $img_w, $img_h);

    // crop image into selected area
    $final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, $cropH);
    imagecolortransparent($final_image, imagecolorallocate($final_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagecopyresampled($final_image, $cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, $imgX1, $imgY1, $cropW, $cropH, $cropW, $cropH);

    // finally output image
    imagejpeg($final_image, $cropped_lrg_filename.$type, $jpeg_quality);







    // now create smaller crop - same aspect ratio just smaller
    // ====================================================================================
    $sml_resized_image = imagecreatetruecolor($sml_resized_w, $sml_resized_h);
    imagecopyresampled($sml_resized_image, $final_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $sml_resized_w, $sml_resized_h, $cropW, $cropH);
    // save it
    imagejpeg($sml_resized_image, $cropped_sml_filename.$type, $jpeg_quality);




    $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'url' => $cropped_lrg_filename.$type
    );
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

**UPDATE**

Below are 2 example images, the first is the resized version (bad quality, yet set to 100% jpeg quality output) and the second is the original image. Look at the stones on the walls, and it's very obvious the reduction in quality.

**cropped**

[image]

**original**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was the `imagerotate()` function. My script was being told to rotate an image even if no rotation had been applied. This caused the image quality to degrade. I've modified the script to read;

```
$rotated_image = $angle == 0 ? $lrg_resized_image : imagerotate($lrg_resized_image, -$angle, 0);
```

There is still a slight unknown here as to why this started to happen, when it wasn't a problem before, and additionally if I do rotate an image, it's still not great, but luckily for this use case that's not likely to be needed anyway.

*Thanks to Golden_flash for helping me debug this*

Comment: Learned quite a lot through this post

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
imageconvolution($original_img,array(array(-1,-1,-1),array(-1,16,-1),array(-1,-1,-1)),8,0);
```

After imagecopyresample and before imagejpeg

Imageconvolution is used to sharpen the image

Comment: That does slightly increase the sharpness, however there's still a visible degradation of the image. This has at least shown me that it's not just blurry...the image is loosing a lot of detail. I've updated my question to show an example. The example is using your tweak, without it, the image is a little worse.

Comment: The reason for degradation of image might be due to making lots of copies by imagecopyresampled , try adding imageconvolution after every call to imagecopyresampled.Can you tell me what you are trying to achieve through the code so that we can cut down some code ?

Comment: The process for this is; 1 image is selected to upload via an interface that allows rotation, zooming and dragging to fit within a crop box, it's indicated whether this is intended for desktop or mobile uplon upload. I need to then save the original at full quality and a cropped version in two different resolutions (regardless of whether it's for mobile or desktop, they just have different resolution criteria). Aside from some basic error checking that's it. I'll try your suggestion now.

Comment: After adding another two instances (1 after each `imagecopyresampled`) of `imageconvolution` the resulting image is far worse - so that's not the way to go.

Comment: The loss in quality is down not to imagecopyresampled(), but to the JPEG compression. Unfortunately, GD's compression algorithms are no match to Photoshop's.According to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345605/php-imagecopyresampled-poor-quality  you should set the value of jpeg quality to 99.This will increase the size but it gives the comparable quality.Try setting jpeg quality now that you have sharpened using imageconvolution.

Comment: It's odd that this used to upload decent quality images at 85%. Tried 99%, but it's still just as bad. It's worth noting that the original image which gets uploaded at the same time does not loose quality. Additionally, I tried reducing the quality of the original image down to 85, and that was nearly indecipherable from the untouched offline image. There's clearly something going on with the crop/resize which is ruining the images.

Comment: I've just tried commenting out the code to rotate the image and hey presto, it's back to good quality...gonna dig around some more see if I can isolate the exact function that's doing it.